# Smart but simple pointers

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

For practice, I've implemented my own smart pointer class. It's a 'unique pointer', meaning it doesn't allow copies of itself (when copying from `a` into `b`, `a` is 'emptied' after the copying, i.e. the raw pointer is set to `0`), so there can never be more than one time where `delete` is called on the raw pointer.

It utilizes RAII to bound the memory deallocation to the object lifetime, so it is just a basic smart pointer.

```
#ifndef SMARTPOINTER_CPP
#define SMARTPOINTER_CPP
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class SmartPointer {
public:
    SmartPointer(T* pointer = NULL) : pointer(pointer) { }
    ~SmartPointer(){
        delete pointer;
    }
    SmartPointer(SmartPointer& other){
        *this = other;
    }
    SmartPointer& operator=(SmartPointer& other){
        this->pointer = other.pointer;
        other.pointer = NULL;

        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() const {
        return *pointer;
    }
    T* operator->() const {
        return pointer;
    }
private:
    T* pointer;
    template <typename E>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<
        (std::ostream& stream, const SmartPointer<E>& smartPointer);
};
template <typename E>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const SmartPointer<E>& smartPointer){
    stream << smartPointer.pointer;
}
#endif
```

Comment: `It's a 'unique pointer'` No its an `auto ptr`. You should implement move semantics to get functionality like `unique ptr`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not `unique_ptr`, it is `auto_ptr`, which has [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697686/what-is-the-problem-with-auto-ptr), mainly that copying a value modifies it, which is counter intuitive.

Assuming you really do not have move semantics and cannot do better (you should, C++11 is old now), there are still some problems:

- There is no way to [release](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/release/) a pointer. If I am not happy with your `SmartPointer` I want to do something like `SmartPointer<T> sp; shared_ptr<T> ssp = sp.release();`.
- You forgot to `return` the `stream` inside `ostream& operator <<`. This should be a compilation error.
- There is no need for `friend`. I don't know who made it popular to make the `ostream& operator <<` a `friend` but I'd like to give that person a stern look. Without `friend` this works just fine:

  ```
  template <typename E>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const SmartPointer<E>& smartPointer){
      return stream << &(*smartPointer);
  }
  ```
- Your copy-constructor is wrong. It copies the pointer eventually resulting in a double `delete`. You probably meant to have `other.pointer = nullptr;`.
- Consider making the assignment operator return `void`. You are supposed to return `*this` to allow chaining like in `a = b = c = nullptr;`. However, since the assignment takes the value away there is no point chaining assignments, so better cause a compiler error.
- Your assignment operator causes a memory leak in the following case:

  ```
  SmartPointer<int> sp1 = new int{1};
  SmartPointer<int> sp2 = new int{2};
  sp1 = sp2;
  ```

  The memory for the first allocation is never `delete`d.

  **Edit:** There is a different memory leak case:

  ```
  SmartPointer<int> sp = new int;
  sp = sp;
  ```

I would suggest `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, but I guess your compiler does not know what that is.

Comment: A copy constructor is all right. It is implemented in terms of assignment, which does nullify `other.pointer` (verified with debugger).

Comment: @vnp I agree with what you wrote, but it does not contradict what I wrote, which confuses me. The nullifying in the assignment works fine, but multiple assignments (like `a = b = c;`) do not make sense. It means the value moves from `c` to `b` to `a`. Why not move directly from `c` to `a` and skip `b`? Returning `void` from the assignment operator allows `a = c;` but not `a = b = c;`. It is a confusing way to nullify `b`.

Comment: I like declaring them as friends it makes sense to define tight coupling and not extend the interface. Also your way precludes the ability to test for NULL. It is obviously part of the interface to the class so friend is a good choice. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99595/12917

Comment: `friend` is needed if you immediatelly **define** the operator inside the class (not later outside). Here it can be done without it if you like `&*` more than accessing private `pointer`.. or even better: public [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) that should be there. Still, friending the operator is a matter of choice, not that bad.

Comment: What should `release()` do? Should it return the inner raw pointer and then null the member?

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes. Same as [`std::auto_ptr<T>::release`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/release/).

Answer (score 6):

#### Main problem is here:

```
SmartPointer& operator=(SmartPointer& other){

    this->pointer = other.pointer;  // you did not delete this->pointer
                                    // before overwritting it.
                                    // So you just leaked a bunch of memory.
    other.pointer = NULL;

    return *this;
}
```

This is why Assignment operators are usually written in terms of the copy constructor. In a patter called "Copy and Swap Idiom."

#### This is strange:

```
SmartPointer(SmartPointer& other){
    *this = other;
}
```

It just looks funky.
If I was going to write this I would have gone:

```
SmartPointer(SmartPointer& other){
    this->operator=(other);
}
```

But even that looks a bit strange as you normally define the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor (see comment above).

#### Usage Problem:

```
T& operator*() const {
    return *pointer;
}
T* operator->() const {
    return pointer;
}
```

Both of these are undefined behavior if the internal pointer is `NULL` (very possible). But there is no way to check the state of the internal pointer. So calling these methods is like playing Russian roulette.

#### Fix output operator

```
template <typename E>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const SmartPointer<E>& smartPointer){
    stream << smartPointer.pointer;
}
```

There does not seem to be a return in this function (yet it declares a return type).

#### Style

I see little point in declaring the output operator as a `friend` and then defining it two lines later. Do it all in a single spot inside the class:

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPointer {
public:
   // STUFF

    // Notice no need for template stuff here now.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const SmartPointer& smartPointer){
         stream << smartPointer.pointer;
    }
};
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) on the `operator<<`? I thought it must be there if you define it inline (inside the class). See section2: *Defines a non-member function, and makes it a friend of this class at the same time. Such non-member function is always inline.*